# Degrees of freedom in a 2^3 factorial experiment without three-way interaction included

Tags: anova, interaction, degrees-of-freedom

I have an ANOVA model with 3 effects (A, B, C) with (a, b, c) levels each and 3 two-way interactions (AB, AC, BC). Within each cell there are n replicates. How to calculate number of degrees of freedom associated with each sum of squares, residuals, in particular?

I have two ideas:

1. It is either the difference between total sum of squares (abcn-1) and all the other known sum of squares

OR

2. abc(n-1) (which is reported in many books for the case when all interactions up to the highest order are included in the model, but in my model there is no ABC interaction), but in this case the total sum of square will be different from abcn-1.

| Effect | Degrees of freedom |
| --- | --- |
| A | a-1 |
| B | b-1 |
| C | c-1 |
| AB | (a-1)(b-1) |
| AC | (a-1)(c-1) |
| BC | (b-1)(c-1) |
| Residuals | ? |
| Total | abcn-1 |